# How do I search a group by its displayName with Cloud Identity REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I am trying to retrieve a group by its `displayName` using the Cloud Identity REST API. As described in [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups/search), it should be possible using the search method with a query parameter as follows:

`parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && displayName == '{groupName}'`

Nonetheless, this request returns a 400 error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 129
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 08:24:44 GMT
server: ESF
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I have also tried the following queries for testing purposes to discard error in the query syntax:

| Query | Response |
| --- | --- |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}'` | Successful |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && 'cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum' in labels` | Successful |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && domain_name == '{domain}'` | Successful |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && groupKey == '{groupEmail}'` | Fails |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && displayName.contains('{groupName}')` | Fails |
| `parent == 'customers/{customerId}' && 'cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum' in labels && displayName == '{groupName}'` | Fails |

So the problem seems to be in the queries using the parameters `displayName` or `groupKey`.

Am I missing something? I thought it might be related to my user's permissions or my **Google Workspace**/**Cloud Identity** tier/configuration, but if so I guess the error would be a 403 as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/searchTransitiveGroups) in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group_key` or `display_name` instead of `groupKey` or `displayName` (ie use Snake Case instead of Camel Case). The docs are wrong in this case.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudidentity_v1.groups.html